# Use database withou ACE.OLEDB provider

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

Is it possible to connect (write, read) to Access database without the ACE.OLEDB provider? 
The problem is that in my company many PC's don't have the provider installed and it is not possible for me to instal it on computers (i'm not part of the IT department), and I would need the admin verification. 
Is there any other way to do it? With some lybrary added to the app? The app is VB.net form app.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an ACCDB file then basically no, it's not possible.  If you use an MDB file then you can use the Jet provider and that is effectively part of Windows these days, so you don't need to install anything extra. ACCDB is the new file format that was introduced Office 2003 along with DOCX for Word, XLSX for Excel, etc.  MDB is the original Access file format that has been supported from the start and still is.  If you're not using any features that are specific to ACCDB then you're not really going to lose anything by using MDB.

One thing I should mention is that ACE is available in both 32-bit and 64-bit flavours, while Jet is 32-bit only.  That said, 64-bit ACE is rare anyway, because anyone who installs Office generally installs the 32-bit version.  What that means is that, if you want to use Jet, your app MUST be 32-bit while you can create a 64-bit app to use ACE but generally need a 32-bit version anyway.

Comment: thank you, 
so the connection string would be something like this:
`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
Data Source=\\serverName\shareName\folder\myDatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;
Password=;`

Comment: That's pretty much it. I don't use Access much but, as far as I'm aware, a Jet connection string is generally all but identical to an ACE connection string. You might double-check [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/).